# Equivariant proper modifications of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper surjective holomorphic map between two $n$-dimensional connected complex manifolds $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is called a proper modification of $Y$ if there are nowhere dense compact analytic subsets $E\subset X$ and $S\subset Y$ such that the following hold:

(1) $f(E)\subset S$. (2) $f$ maps $X\setminus E$ biholomorphically onto $Y\setminus S$. (3) Every fibre $f^{−1}(y)$, $y\in S$, consists of more than one point.

Consider the standard torus action on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ given by the torus 
$\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_{1}},\ldots,e^{i\theta_{n}})$, where $\theta_{k}\in\mathbb{R}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Let $f:X→\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a proper modification of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ that is equivariant with respect to this torus action, i.e., the torus action on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ lifts to $X$ and the lifted action is equivariant with respect to $f$. Then is $X$ necessarily an iterated blowup of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ at the origin?

The equivariance condition implies that the modification can only take place at the fixed point of the torus action on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, i.e., the origin, so that $f^{-1}(\{x)\})$ is one point for all $x\neq0$. Clearly, $X$ as the blowup of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ at the origin is an example. Further examples are obtained by blowing up along the exceptional $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ at the fixed points of the induced action on this set, and so on. My question is, are all such examples obtained in this manner?

Comment: You can also blowup at a torus invariant line, or plane, or other torus-invariant subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ at the second step.

Comment: I think you can only blow up at points fixed under the induced action of the whole torus on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, not just some subtorus, in order for the action of the whole torus to lift to the resultant blowup which is what I want. I think these fixed points are just $[1:0:\ldots:0]$, $[0:1:0:\ldots:0]$, etc. hence my thoughts in the last paragraph above.

Comment: If $(x_1:\dots:x_n)$ are the homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, the line $x_3 = x_4 = \dots x_n = 0$ is invariant with respect to the whole torus.

Comment: So every holomorphic vector field generated by the induced torus action on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ blown up at a point would lift when you further blow up along the line $x_{3}=\ldots=x_{n}=0$ in the exceptional $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$? This should be the case if the torus action extended to this further blow up. I thought a vector field would lift to the blowup if and only if it vanished along the variety being blown up.